# Inferior Bar not Summing properly on ArrayFormulas

Tags: google-sheets

I had the sheet working perfectly without any problem. And one moment without making anything to my formulas, the sum of hours and minutes in the inferior bar stopped summing as an hour but in decimals. I give you this example:

If I click 2 cells with formatted as hour (A1 = 00:01:00 + A2 = 00:02:00) it should appear on the inferior bar the result of 00:03:00, but now it appears as decimals number (0,005).

This only happens on my array formulas, for example:

```
=ArrayFormula(D94/IFERROR(INDEX(Art!Q$4:Q$500;MATCH(1;($G94=Art!$D$4:$D$500)*($F94=Art!$C$4:$C$500)*($H94=Art!$E$4:$E$500)*(COUNTIF($A$45:$A94;Art!$D$4:$D$500)=0);0));""))/24
```

In the past was working perfectly. Nothing has changed in the overall sheet.

I think that the devs must have changed something on the google sheets that is making this bug now.

Anyone knows how to fix this or to go around this problem?

[image: With Array Formula]

[image: Without Array Formula]

First image has arrayformula, second dont.

Comment: Hi there @soldcarvalho! In order to understand your scenario better, could you please share an example Sheet?

Comment: Hello. I have uploaded 2 images on the end of my question. That are the examples. Can you see them? If you see, they have on the bottom right a "Soma / Sum".